# Using json file in netbeans 8

Tags: php, json, symfony, netbeans, composer-php

Just started to use composer option in netbeans 8 with symfony2 on WAMP. I have linked composer.bat in options/composer. I'm able to create json by running init from project window command. By default symfony json file is based one level up than netbeans is lookin in. How to force netbeans to use json file which is not directly in project level but the one in in symfony folder?

Comment: If you are trying to use Netbeans to create a new Symfony project, it is far easier to follow Symfony's directions on creating a new project.  When done, use Netbeans to create a new project from existing files.  Point Netbeans to the project's top-level directory.  This, at least, is how I've always done it.

Comment: whichever way you do, you will get same result when it comes to project path(top-level). It is composer from netebans menu i have issue with. Usually you get something like ProjectName->SymfonyProject->SymfonyFiles(including json file). When you run compser option it looks up in  ProjectName->SymfonyProject instead in ProjectName->SymfonyProject->SymfonyFiles

Comment: AFAIK, Netbeans Composer options are intended to operate on a global installation of composer, not on a specific project's composer json. This assumption is based on the setting of the location of composer in Tools, Options, PHP, Framework & Tools, Composer.

Comment: Composer settings are poiting to the right composer.bat file. I have no issues running composer command from cmd either. Using composer->init from netbeans creates json file with mininum settings in 'Source File' folder but Symfony project resides in 'Source File'->'SymfonyProject'. Main issue is how to run composer commands not on json based in 'Source File' but on the one below it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: It is not possible to specify composer .json file path in netbeans please see link https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251322